# How can i clear the TexBox (textbox.text) control in a user control

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have a user control that has a textbox in it, and i am using a clear button on my main form to clear information from the entire main window. i would like to clear the textbox in the user control once the clear button is clicked as well. i have tried referencing the control's name in c# followed by a "." however the name of the text box does not show up. any help would be appreciated!

I tried in so many ways,But..no result:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        for(int k = 0; k< this.Controls.Count;k++)
        {
            if(this.Controls[k] is MyUserControl)
            {
                MyUserControl _obj = this.Controls[k] as MyUserControl;
                for (int i = 0; i < _obj.Controls.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (_obj.Controls[i].GetType().ToString() == "TextBox")
                        (_obj.Controls[i] as TextBox).Clear();
                 }
            }      
         }
```

Or I am creating one method in usercontrol

```
       public void clear()
       {
         txtname.Text = String.empty;
       }
```

Then I am calling clear() method from my current form like.

```
         usercontrol  uc = new usercontrol();
         uc.clear();
```

But I am unable clear the text present in usercontrol

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop change these lines

```
if (_obj.Controls[i] is TextBox)
{
   TextBox clearTextBox = _obj.Controls[i] as TextBox;
   clearTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            for (int k = 0; k < this.Controls.Count; k++) 
                {
                if (this.Controls[k] is MyUserControl)
                    {
                    MyUserControl _obj = this.Controls[k] as MyUserControl; 
                    for (int i = 0; i < _obj.Controls.Count; i++) 
                        {
                        if (_obj.Controls[i] is TextBox)
                            {
                            ((TextBox)_obj.Controls[i]).Clear();
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will improve the performance as skipping looping to search the text box. And gives flexibility to have multiple textboxes in in your user control.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        for (int k = 0; k < this.Controls.Count; k++) 
            {
            if (this.Controls[k] is MyUserControl)
                {
                MyUserControl _obj = this.Controls[k] as MyUserControl; 
                 if (_obj != null)
                   {((TextBox)_obj.FindControl("yourTextBoxID")).Text = string.Empty;}
                } 
            }
        }
```